# Error in Building APK

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got this error when building APK.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: java_cup/runtime/ComplexSymbolFactory$ComplexSymbol.class

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.wiserlab.macquest'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // Mapbox dependencies
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile('com.cocoahero.android:geojson:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Mapbox Android UI
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-ui:2.1.3'
    // Mapbox Navigation SDK for Android
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile files('src/main/jniLibs/spatialite-android-library.jar')
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.0'
    compile 'nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka:weka-dev:3.9.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.0'
}
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you need this: "multiDexEnabled true" ?  You should add a debug buildType without proguard and see if the app builds.  If it is then it's a proguard issue and you should post your proguard rules.

Comment: @LouMorda Have you import any module or project?